# Weight painting is broken after applying transforms with large scale

Tags: weight-painting

I have observed that Weight Paint mode stops working under the following steps:

1. Create new Plane
2. Scale it up 2x with `S 2`
3. Switch to Edit Mode, subdivide the Plane by 10
4. Switch to Weight Paint Mode, verify that weight painting works
5. Switch to Object Mode, Apply All Transforms to Plane
6. Switch to Weight Paint Mode, verify that weight painting still works
7. Delete the Plane.
8. Repeat steps 1-8 with a 10000x scale, and note that step 6 fails.
9. Stranger still, repeat steps 1-8 *with the original 2x scale* and note that step 6 now fails!

This must be a bug, right? Something seems to be broken when weight painting the large mesh that then sticks around and pollutes the global state for all future weight painting.

Blender 3.2.1.

Comment: I couldn't replicate the problem in Blender 3.4. It looks like it's a simple zoom view problem: as weight is a property of vertices, if you paint over a face nothing happens. With a scale of 10000 it's easy to paint in a zone where there aren't any vertices, so it feels like broken. Activate wireframe overlay and try again.

Comment: Why are you using version 3.2.1 when 3.3.3 is the current long-term supported version?